# Is there a way to parallelize a function inside a pool in Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, emcee

I am trying to parallelize a function inside a pool using the `multiprocessing` module, but I run into the error:

> daemonic processes are not allowed to have children

More specifically, I am using `emcee` module which makes use of the `multiprocessing` module for parallelization, and I would like to parallelize my posterior function as well to speed up the calculations. Is there a way to parallelize a function inside the main `Pool` in this case?

**Edit (code added)**:

```
# defines the log-posterior probability distribution
def logp(p):

    mu_imf, mu_h0, sigma_h, b_h = p
    
    logpost = np.zeros(ngal, dtype='longdouble')
    
    for i in range(ngal):
        logpost[i] = np.log(quad(lambda m_halo: Integrand(m_halo, i, mu_imf, mu_h0, sigma_h, b_h), 11.9, 15.0107)[0])
        
    return np.sum(logpost) 

with Pool() as pool:
    sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, npars, logp, pool=pool)
```

Answer (score 2):

In general you don't want to do that.  Parallelising parallel processes can explode very quickly.  It also is likely not much quicker, as there is an overhead in spinning up a new process.

Rather than trying to parallelise everything at once, parallelise in two steps.  First generate all the emcee tasks you are interested in, and parallelise your processing, as [in the docs](https://emcee.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/parallel/?highlight=parallel#).  Then aggregate your results to a queue, and map your posterior function over *that*.

I.e., rather than having your current setup, parallelising this:

```py
def do_work(**params):
    some_results = do_emcee_call_in_parallel(**params)
    do_stuff_with_some_results(some_results)
```

Where you've split your problem into two chunks, do this:

```py
problems = get_all_problems()
results = parallel_solve_emcee_problems(problems)
pool = Pool()
pool.map(posterior, results) # etc
```

Alternatively, if I've misunderstood what you're trying to do, feel free to show what your desired inputs and outputs are.

Comment: @ 2e0byo Thank you very much for your help. I was trying to figure out how I can implement what you have described, but I am still not sure how to do that. The problem is that I have to pass the function **logp** to **emcee.EnsembleSampler**. The **logp** function however, is a computationally expensive function and contains an inevitable for loop and hence, I would like to parallelize it. I have now added the **logp** function as well as how `emcee` makes use of it to my question.